# Get customer comment

Tags: magento-1.8, soap, onestepcheckout

For some reason my checkout module save customer comment under **['additional_information']['checkoutmodule'][0]['value']**

At invoice PDF I'm able to add this with below code:

```
    /* Add customer comment */
    $orderData = $order->getPayment()->getData();
    $orderComment = $orderData['additional_information']['checkoutmodule'][0]['value'];
    if($orderComment){
        $page->drawText('Customer comment:', 35, $this->y-45, 'UTF-8');
        $page->drawText($orderComment, 35, $this->y-55, 'UTF-8');
    }
```

However I need to access this information using SOAP as well. However, I can not find this value anywhere. Any idea how I could access it?

Also, is this place the actual place where customer_comment should be saved?

Comment: Magento doesn't have a customer comment. Most of the time I misuse gift message

Comment: Ok, that explains. I would prefer having it there as well. I found this code in:  **app\code\community\Made\checkoutmodule\Model\Sales\Observer.php**

`$observer->getEvent()
                ->getPayment()
                ->setAdditionalInformation('checkoutmodule', $custom)`

So my guess is that I need to stick with their solution as this is considered to be a custom field. However. I need to come up with a way to get it using Soap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve it. It was easier then I thought. I was looking for it in **sales_order.info_list** however I needed to check the actual order and the Payment part.

Anyhow, here's the code:

```
  $shipdata = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.info', $list['increment_id']);
  echo $orderComment = $shipdata['payment']['additional_information']['checkoutmodule'][0]['value'];
```